# Take image input from folder and after resizing store it to a output folder

Tags: php, image-processing

I need to take sequence of images as input from a folder and after resizing, the resized image should be stored on an output folder. I wrote code. But in my code after resizing image, output folder only has a black image.

To debug this code please create input & output folder and put some gif image on input folder and see the output on output folder. Please help.

```
<?php
$dir = opendir("input/");
$i   = 0;
while ($imgfile = readdir($dir))
  {
    if ($imgfile != "." && $imgfile != "..")
      {
        $imgarray[$i] = $imgfile;
        $newwidth     = 240; //new width
        $newheight    = 320; //new height
        $uploadedfile = $imgarray[$i];
        $src          = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploadedfile);
        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
        $filename = "output/" . $imgarray[$i];
        imagegif($tmp, $filename, 100);
        imagedestroy($src);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
        $i++;
      }
  }
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
$uploadedfile = $imgarray[$i];
```

Your images are in the input folder, but this is setting the variable to just the image name, so when you try calling `imagecreatefromgif` and `getimagesize` it is not finding an image, resulting in the black output you are getting. To fix, just add the correct directory before the name:

```
$uploadedfile = "input/" . $imgarray[$i];
```

Tested with this change and it works.

As a side note, I was able to *quickly* find what was wrong with your code by having error_reporting on:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

By doing this, you will get warning messages and such that you may not see otherwise. These can be the difference between a quick fix and tearing your hair out for hours. Use it when you are debugging.

Comment: can u pls help me to use:

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

How I use it or add the code on which portion? i don’t use it before.

Comment: You would add the code at the very top of your script. You could also modify your php.ini so that by default this is the behavior (as I believe it is) and then modify it on the top so that it is not when you are in production.